# How to extract selective data from a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have only a question with no sample code.

I am building a project management website for home inspections using html and javascript.

I get a standard email that comes with every new home inspection project assignment, and it is formatted the same with reliable row labels every time.  In my email viewer, I'd Select All then Copy the email body and Paste into a textbox.  When I submit the form with that textbox, I want to find the data on each row.  A row might be "Floor type: Tile", and I want to assign a variable to "Tile" or whatever the data is for each row.

I have been doing this with an Excel macro written in Visual Basic, and in that code, I find certain characters or a string of characters then use + and - to get to the actual string I want.  I have searched a lot but can't seem to phrase my needs correctly and have not found any answer for my situation.

Input would be pasted into a textbox...
Type:  Normal
Date of Loss: 04/09/2019
Claim Number:   XFP636

and then I'd like to set variables for example as follows:

$type = (Find the row with “Type:” and extract the string after the “:”)
$dateofloss = (Find the row with “Date of Loss:” and extract the string after the “:”)
$claimnumber = (Find the row with “Claim Number:” and extract the string after the “:”)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should show us a sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added an example in your question so I will show here a specific answer for it using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp):

```js
let input = "Type: Normal Date of Loss: 04/09/2019 Claim Number: XFP636"

//type dateofloss claimnumber 

let type = input.match(/Type: (\w*)/)[1];
let re = new RegExp("Date of Loss: (\\d+/\\d+/\\d*)");
let dateofloss = input.match(re)[1];
let claimnumber = input.match(/Claim Number: (\w*)/)[1]

console.log(type, dateofloss, claimnumber);
```

**OLD Answer:**
You didn't specify any input nor desired output, just:

> Can anyone help to at least point me in the right direction?

So this is my point:

You can use `"".split()` to get the values.

```js
let input = "Type: Normal Date of Loss: 04/09/2019 Claim Number: XFP636";

//type dateofloss claimnumber Type: Normal Date of Loss: 04/09/2019 Claim Number: XFP636

let stuffs = ["Floor", "Roof", "Windows", "Bedrooms", "Living Rooms"];
let result = [];
for (let line of input.split("\n")) {
  for (let type of stuffs) {
    splitted = line.split(type + " type: ");
    if (splitted.length == 2) {
      result.push(splitted[1]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Or you might use a Regrex:

```js
let input = `Floor type: Tile
Roof type: Classic
Windows type: Double Insulate
Bedrooms type: Espacious
Living Rooms type: None`

let stuffs = ["Floor", "Roof", "Windows", "Bedrooms", "Living Rooms"];
let result = [];

for (let type of stuffs) {
  let re = new RegExp(type + " type: (\\w*)")
  let get = input.match(re);
  if (get.length == 2) {
    result.push(get[1]);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

You can improve this using a dictionary instead of just a simple array, so you can know better each type.

Comment: Sincere thanks again Ender Look.  I'll pursue this method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the formatted email and format it using JSON format, then with the copy/paste into a textbox you can extract the information using JSON.parse().

Comment: Thanks David IX.  How would I reformat an email to json format?  It's just a normal email and I just CTRL+A then CTRL+C to copy the whole body.

Comment: What you need to do is to change the form of how email is redacted, something like this:

{
   "field1": 12345, 
   "field2": "text 1", 
   "field3": "text 2", 
   "field4": "text 3"
}

field is the parameter name and after the colon is the value.

So you can copy/paste in a textbox and get the information with JSON.parse()